# Can't exit from R console command in R studio

Tags: r, function, console, rstudio

I ran some code containing some functions, and apparently a there was a curly bracket mismatch. However, I got stuck in the console, and can't get back to the command prompt, everything I type is considered as continuation of the last command. I tried to type a few thing but it didn't help. ^z did not help either. I finally had to restart the session. Is there any other way?
[image]

Comment: it seems you don't have curly brackets in pairs (see line 480). Probably you will resolve the problem once you fix that issue.

Comment: Try to press the `esc` button on the keyboard.

Comment: Ctrl +c (^c) was a gamechanger for me